# How I prevent a plugin to be loaded when doing WP-CLI?

Tags: plugins, wp-cli

I currently use this code in the main plugins file itself. But that plugin is not my own so I would prefer to be able to upgrade it normally without every time adding this code.

```
if ( defined( 'WP_CLI' ) && WP_CLI ) {
    exit;
}
```

I need to do this because this plugin produces errors and stops wp-cli to execute correctly so I can't just disable the plugin with wp-cli, do my tasks and re-enable it.

Is there a way I can do something like `if x then do not load plugin file x` from within a mu-plugin?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

One of the first things WordPress does to load plugins is get the active plugins as saved in the database:

```
$active_plugins = (array) get_option( 'active_plugins', array() );
```

Since it uses `get_option()` we can use the [`option_active_plugins`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/option_option/) filter to modify the list of active plugins on the fly.

```
function wpse_301282_disable_plugin( $active_plugins ) {
    if ( defined( 'WP_CLI' ) && WP_CLI ) {
        $key = array_search( 'gravityforms/gravityforms.php', $active_plugins );

        if ( $key ) {
            unset( $active_plugins[$key] );
        }
    }

    return $active_plugins;
}
add_filter( 'option_active_plugins', 'wpse_301282_disable_plugin' );
```

Just replace `gravityforms/gravityforms.php` with the directory and filename of the plugin you want to disable.

The problem here is that we are trying to affect the loading of plugins, so we can't do that from *within* a plugin, because it's too late. In the theme would also be too late.

Thankfully WordPress has ["Must Use Plugins"](https://codex.wordpress.org/Must_Use_Plugins) these are plugins you can add that are loaded before and separately to regular plugins, and do not appear in the regular plugins list.

All you need to do to add this code to a Must Use Plugin is to create a `wp-content/mu-plugins` directory (if it doesn't already exist) and create a PHP file (it can be called anything) with that code in it. You don't need a plugin header or anything else.

Now that code will be loaded before all other plugins when WordPress loads. Since our filter is in place, when WordPress gets the list of active plugins to load the plugin you want to disable will be filtered out of that list if WP-CLI is active.

Comment: Had the same idea but this doesn't work. At least not in my local environment. Maybe `get_option()` is returning early when the value is saved in transients/similar and this filter is skipped? (Doesn't work for most cases, only in the admin plugin screen it actually got executed)

Comment: Hm. Looking at the source and as far as I can tell the only reason the `option_` filter wouldn't be applied is if it doesn't have a value and is returning the default.

Comment: That was actually the case (no plugins active). I shouldn't keep my test environments too clean ..

Comment: I accepted this because in my case its what I needed. Even though in general the `--skip-plugin=x` option of wp-cli may be a better way to do it.

Answer (score 23):

You can use the `skip-plugins` option in WP-CLI to not load individual plugins when using WP-CLI.

You can either use it in command like this:

```
wp user list --skip-plugins=my-plugin
```

Or you can add this to your `wp-cli.yml` file:

```
skip-plugins:
- my-plugin
```

Answer (score -3):

Just re-naming the plugin dir name will disable it. I do it sometimes to temporarily disable a plugin [linux]:

```
mv my-plugin-dir renamed-my-plugin-dir
```

Comment: The OP want to skip the plugin just when using WP-CLI, not for any other activity that might happen at the same time